# CSS hover specificity issue

Tags: html, css

I have the first row of a table styled as follows:

```
.Table1 tr:first-child td { ... }
```

I also want a hover style on part of this row, and I've tried these 2 as the next rule, but neither of them works:

```
.Table1 tr:first-child:hover td { ... }
.Table1 tr:first-child td:hover { ... }
```

They do both partially work - some `td` cells in the row have no content, and have a class of `emptyColumn`, and these cells *do* have the hover styling applied to them (but only if the styling is `!important`). However, the cells which do have text content are *not* styled.

From my (very) limited understanding of specificity, if the first rule actually works, then surely the second rule should also work, since it's more specific? Is there something else that could stop it working?

However, what I actually need is slightly different from this. I only want the hover to work on certain `td` cells in the `tr`, and I've given these cells a class of `colHeaderButton`:

```
td.setAttribute('class', 'colHeaderButton');
```

I can't find any way to apply the `hover` style using the class name - I've tried various combinations such as

```
.Table1.colHeaderButton tr:first-child td:hover { ... }
```

but I can't get any of these to work. Thanks.

Comment: If your `td` elements have that class, then you should _select_ `td` elements with that class … instead you are trying to select elements that have the class `Table1` as well. This does not seem to be a specificity issue … but more an issue of you not really knowing what you’re doing when it comes to selectors in general. And what do you actually want to trigger something here – the hover state on the whole table row, or just on the specific table cell …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `td` is a member of the class, not the `table`.

```
.Table1 tr:first-child td.colHeaderButton:hover
```